# Confused about setting median values of a coloured image

Tags: java, android, algorithm, sorting, bitmap

I am implementing a median filter in Java using a Bitmap image. I am using an algorithm implemented in another programming language and then converting it to Java for my implementation. The part of the algorithm that I do not understand is below:

```
for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) 
for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) 
{ 
    int n = 0;
    //set the color values in the arrays
    for(int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
    for(int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
    {
        int imageX = (x - filterWidth / 2 + filterX + w) % w;
        int imageY = (y - filterHeight / 2 + filterY + h) % h;
        red[n] = image[imageX][imageY].r;
        green[n] = image[imageX][imageY].g;
        blue[n] = image[imageX][imageY].b;
        n++;
    }
```

Here is the link to the [Median Algorithm](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html#Median)

I implemented the following code myself but I dont think it is correct. I would appreciate if someone can help me please.

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
        { 
            int n = 0;
            for(int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)

                for(int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
                {

                    pixel = image.getPixel(x,y);  
                    A = (pixel>>24) & 0xFF;
                    R = (pixel>>16) & 0xFF;
                    G = (pixel>>8) & 0xFF;
                    B = pixel & 0xFF;

                    RArray[n] = R;
                    GArray[n] = G;
                    BArray[n] = B;
                    n++;

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where you are selecting the median of the input values. As Jim mentioned, be sure to handle the edge cases, for example...

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
    { 
        int index = 0;
        for(int filterX = -filterWidth/2; filterX < filterWidth/2; filterX++)
            for(int filterY = -filterHeight/2; 
                 filterY < filterHeight/2; filterY++)
        {
            int pixelX = x+filterX;
            int pixelY = y+filterY;

            //ensure we're in bounds.
            if(pixelX>-1 && pixelY>-1 && pixelX<w && pixelY<h){
                pixel = image.getPixel(x,y);
                A = (pixel>>24) & 0xFF;
                R = (pixel>>16) & 0xFF;
                G = (pixel>>8) & 0xFF;
                B = pixel & 0xFF;

                RArray[index] = R;
                GArray[index] = G;
                BArray[index] = B;
                ++index;
        }
   }
   //only sort the pieces of the array we've put data into,
   //remember we could be on an edge of the image.
   Arrays.sort(RArray,0,index);
   Arrays.sort(BArray,0,index);
   Arrays.sort(GArray,0,index);
   int medianR = RArray[RArray.length/2];
   int medianB = BArray[BArray.length/2];
   int medianG = GArray[GArray.length/2];

   //last step is to combine medians back into a single integer
```

Comment: Hi, you are correct it is a 3x3 kernel but the algorithm provided in the link is a median and thats what I am trying to implement and thats the part I dont understand.

Comment: My implementation may be wrong however, the algorithm provided in the link should be a median filter.

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, is your implementation a median or a convolution algorithm

Comment: It was convolution, I've changed it. @RigaKdot

Comment: Ok cool, I will choose this answer as the correct answer but can you please paste it using ALL the code I provided. Would be better so noone has to keep scrolling up and down =) Thanks so much

Comment: Yep. I'm actually trying to write a more full example for you sir. One moment. I may make a mistake here... arrays are easy to get wrong haha. It will be a good example though.

Comment: Thanks William, appreciate your time and help

Comment: @RigaKdot No problem!  Love this stuff. Did research on it in college. The new example should clear up all your confusion here.

Comment: are you sure that the algorithm is right for the edge calculation?

Comment: How do you mean? The general idea of it, yeah. The code having no mistakes? No. There's only 2 ways to handle edges, you can't use the full search area and wide up with odd edges, or you wrap left/right, top/bottom and wind up with strange results most the time anyway.

Comment: The problem I am having is that the app crashes when I run this code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to analyze N pixels and find the middle value to get the median.
You need to use the changing filterX and filterY values as offsets to get other pixels than just x and y.

getPixel(x+filterX,y+filterY)

Comment: How can I use that with the RGB colour space? Can you put some code up please? It will just help me understand better.

Comment: What you have is fine.  You get the pixel (3 bands) and calc. median for each.  You have to sum each array and divide by n. The top example offsets the filters so that the pixel x,y is at the center of the median.  You might want to do that.  Also, I'm not sure how you are handling edge effects as the offset might take you over the edge of the image.

Comment: @Jim No. You're describing the average. I made the same mistake in my answer initially. Dividing gets you the average. The median is less affected by outliers, highly desirable when removing noise.

Comment: valx = max(0,min(x+filterX,width);  valy = max(0,min(y+filterY,height);  //This deals (crudely) with edge effects so you won't seg fault accessing something beyond the image region

Comment: William, you are right.  Median is middle value of the N values in the array. My mistake.

Comment: @jim Yeah haha, we both got carried away here a little. +1 for being a good... uhh... overflower. :)